# Android - how to search MySQL database with multiple criteria using PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a database with football players from FIFA and I'm able to search it from my Android application based on their names. I want to be able to search it based on the players rating as well, but I'm not able to do that.

This is how I try to send the two criteria I have (player name and rating) from my application and this is where it doesn't work. It works if I just have one `Uri.builder()` with the `searchQuery` variable which is the name of the player. But when I try to add another `Uri.builder()` with the variable `minRating` it can't make the connection to the database.

```
  // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from PHP and MySQL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput to true as we send and recieve data
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // add parameter to our above url
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            Uri.Builder builder2 = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("minRating", minRating);
            String minRating = builder2.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.write(minRating);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();
```

This is how I receive the data with my PHP-file and query the database:

```
<?php
 include 'config.inc.php';

 if(isset($_POST['searchQuery']))
 {
      $search_query=$_POST['searchQuery'];
      $min_rating=$_POST['minRating'];

      $sql = "SELECT Name, Club_Position, Rating from spillere where Name LIKE '%$search_query%'
              AND Rating > $min_rating";

      $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $statement->bindParam(':search_query',$search_query, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $statement->execute();
      if($statement->rowCount())
      {
    $row_all = $statement->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($row_all);
      }  
      elseif(!$statement->rowCount())
      {
    echo "no rows";
      }
 }    
 ?>
```

This is what my stack trace looks like:

[Image of stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyhSf.png)

How can I take two or more search criteria from my Android application, send it to the PHP-file and query the database?

Comment: but you already send two parameters `searchQuery` and `minRating`. You can do the same to send further parameters. Or what exactly do you want?

Comment: @Edwin Sorry for not making it clear. I can't send both of the parameters I can only send (`searchQuery`) . When I try to send (`minRating`) it doesn't work. So there must be something wrong with the way that I use the (`Uri.builder`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery);
 String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

 Uri.Builder builder2 = new Uri.Builder().appendQueryParameter("minRating", minRating);
 String minRating = builder2.build().getEncodedQuery();
```

Combine both above parameter in single Query Parameter:

```
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
             .appendQueryParameter("searchQuery", searchQuery)
             .appendQueryParameter("minRating", minRating);
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

//Now write query param to OutputStream 
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple solution to an annoying problem :)